# Database schema for getting started with a Content Management System

Tags: java, content-management-system, content-management

Hi 
I'm starting development of a small content management system but struggling to figure out how to get started. Does any one know where I can get a database schema or how such a system is developed.

There are loads of CMS systems but none allow you to embed them in  an application and that is why I need to develop this.

any ideas will be very much welcomed

A java based system will be preffered.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a high volume of quality answers with this question.  Its very broad.  What do you need your CMS to do? That should drive the database structure, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) as the content store. You would still need to write the UI yourself. There are CMSs which provide a UI based on Jackrabbit (or another implementation of the JCR API), but i don't know if any are embeddable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't Java but if it's only the DB schema you want you could begin by Installing [Webmatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix) and selecting one of the templates.  Then you can take a look at the schema they have and go from there.